Python Variables - Memory Management - Reference Count
I am a beginner in python.
i have executed the following :
x=5
id(x)
140717517440040
id(5)
140717517440040
y=5
id(y)
140717517440040
id(5)
140717517440040
import sys
print(sys.getrefcount(x))
4294967295
print(sys.getrefcount(5))
4294967295

I received the above values.
But when i executed the following:
mcavar=12345678901
id(m1)
1265225292816
id(12345678901)
1265225292976
s1=12345678901
id(s1)
1265225293296
id(12345678901)
1265225292976
print(sys.getrefcount(12345678901))
2
print(sys.getrefcount(m1))
2
print(sys.getrefcount(s1))
2

I received the above.
When i executed for x and y variables i received the same memory address. But when executed for m1 and s1 for the same value, i am getting different memory address. But for the value it is providing the same memory address. But for variable it is providing different address for m1 and s1. Why? Please clarify it

Low value ints are preallocated in memory for efficiency because they are used so often; higher values are created in memory as computed.
